# Process Closes Immediately

Tags: c#, .net, process

So, I am trying to install CCleaner silently by using the code below, but what I've noticed, is that CCleaner closes immediately and doesn't actually install.

There is no exceptions being thrown or anything, so I am at a loss. Anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong here?

```
    String path = String.Format(@"{0}\CCleaner.exe", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = path;
    startInfo.Arguments = @"/S";
    Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
    p.WaitForInputIdle();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Dispose();
```

Comment: What is `CCleaner.exe`? Where did you get it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman LMGTFY: https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: Okay smarty pants ( ;) ). Which version? The installer is called `ccsetupXXX.exe`, not `CCleaner.exe`...

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was just commenting regarding *What is* ... Nothing more, nothing less. Your other question seems legit though!

Comment: CCleaner is a 3rd party free application that supposed to clean up your system, fix registry error's etc... @Ceus when you debug this code.. which I hope you are debugging... what line does it error on..also what are you running this from what is the value of `path` when you step past the first line in your code..?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: That first question was strictly for OP. He should tell us, we shouldn't need to google for the file he uses.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I know this is quite subjective, but CCleaner is *broadly*  known (at least to me). So for me, at least, there was no need to google... And from my understanding, I can just jump in to, at least, clarify what CCleaner is, can't I? Sorry that I did not incoporate any obvious sign for sarcasm though!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: Yes, but these kind of questions tend to down when the OP uses an exotic version downloaded months ago, and we try to figure it out using latest. He should include a link to the exact EXE he is using. (And btw, I have been using CC from day one)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Getting this information (head? version? link?) might have been the intention of your initial comment, but - obviously - not that obvious :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find out what causes the process to exit, check its output and error messages:

```
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

I would guess that in the given context, you do not have sufficient rights to install a program and therefore the installer exits immediately.